# How doctrine loggable extension stores history in the database? Can I change it?

Tags: doctrine, stofdoctrineextensions

I'm searching around all web.. but not found reply to this question. For logging changes in my project entities I want use stof doctrine extension - loggable, but it's not obvious for me, how   changes in the entities are stored in the database? Can I define my own table for history and write changes of some fields in the entities there?

And so where is located loggable configuration about stroring history in the database? I red manual but not found a bit information about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If configured correctly, once you update your database, a table called ext_log_entries
 will be created; That is where the changes are stored.